# Joins in multiple table

Tags: sql, join

I want to fetch records (Class, Subject, Chapter, ModuleName, AccessTime, LoginTime, IpAddress and Email) from below tables, main fields of the tables are shown in bracket ().

```
 ct_user (user_Id, email)
 ct_user_log (user_id, ip_address, login_time, sessionId)
 ct_user_module_log (module_id, module_open_time,user_id, ip_address, sessionId) 
 ct_user_module (module_id, module_name, subject_id, chapter_id, topic_id, board_class_id)
 ct_subject (subject_id, subject_name)
 ct_board_class (board_class_id, class_name, board_id, class_id)
 ct_class_subject_topic (topic_id, topic_name, board_class_id, topic_level)
```

Comment: Thanks for informing us that you want to fetch records. Do you have any question?

Comment: You should use select from all tables with join on key columns.